# How to copy the contents of a file to a new file, given a file pointer?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, copy

In C on a linux machine, given a file pointer to a file in the current directory, how can I copy the contents of that file into a new file in a sub directory.

With the directory structure (home, and the file and directory names are arbitrary):

```
home/
  |________file.txt
  |________source.c
  |________subdirectory/
```

I want the `source.c` file to make a `system()` call that will create a file named `copy.txt` (the name is arbitrary) in `subdirectory/`, and copy the contents of `file.txt` to the copy file.

The resulting directory structure would be:

```
home/
  |________file.txt
  |________source.c
  |________subdirectory/
             |________copy.txt
```

where file.txt and copy.txt have the exact same contents.

Comment: 1) `fopen` the source file in read mode ("r"), 2) `fopen` the copy in write mode ("w"), 3) `fread` from source, 4) `fwrite` to destination, 5) `fclose` both files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have a stream pointer open on the source file, you cannot make a copy by calling `system`, but it is easy to copy the contents directly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int copyfile(FILE *f1) {
    long pos;
    FILE *f2;
    int c;

    if (mkdir("subdirectory", 0644))
        return -1;
    if ((f2 = fopen("subdirectory/copy.txt", "w")) == NULL)
        return -1;
    pos = ftell(f1);
    rewind(f1);
    while ((c = getc(f1)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, f2);
    }
    fseek(pos, SEEK_SET, f1);
    return fclose(f2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the source file, you can call

```
system("mkdir subdirectory && cp ./file.txt ./subdirectory/copy.txt");
```

This will first create the subdirectory and then copy the file to it.